# Play Game Services (Real time games) with Parse.com security

Tags: security, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, google-play-games

How can I provide security for the game from hackers? I'm making the game with Google Game Services (sign in and real time multiplayer 1vs1) and with Parse.com for data storage.

developers.google.com notify:

> Warning: Data that is sent using Game services is unencrypted. Since messages can originate from any peer client connected to the room, you should treat this data as untrusted. We recommend that you implement your own security checking to verify that inbound data does not compromise your app.

And how can I safely  write player level progress to parse.com, for example?
I cannot write something like:

```
if (expirianceUp) {
  WriteToServer(newExpirianceVal);
}
```

I think it is no safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hash the value with a key like hmac-md5. Using same key on parse.com, decrypt hashed value and parse to int or whatever your data type. Use [cloud code](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions) to dcrypt.